# Preserve function context in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm having a function in Python that when being called first, reads the content of a file to a list and checks whether or not an element is within that list.

```
def is_in_file(element, path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    return element in lines
```

When the function is being called again, however, the content of the file should not be read again; the function should instead remember the value of `lines` from the first call.

Is there a way to preserve the context of a function when calling the function again? I don't want to make `lines` global to not litter the above namespace. I guess it's quite similar to the use of a generator and the `yield` statement...

Comment: Seems like a typical use case of a `class`.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is that the correct way is to encapsulate this in a class. The path is set at instance creation, and method calls use the list of lines. That way you can even have different *files* at the same time:

```
class finder:
   def __init__(self, path):
       with open(path, 'r') as f:
           self.lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
   def is_in_file(self, element):
       return element in lines
```

That is not exactly what you have asked for, but is much more OO.

Comment: This is the better solution, in the long run.

Comment: You could even give that class a `__call__` method such that it feels like a function.

Answer (score 2):

Dirty hack: add variable to function object and store value there.

```
def is_in_file(element, path):
    if not hasattr(is_in_file, "__lines__"):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            setattr(is_in_file, "__lines__", [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])
    return element in is_in_file.__lines__
```

Comment: Interesting idea. But certainly quite hacky :-)

Comment: Given the function signature cannot be changed or encapsulated in a class why is this hacky? it is the equivalent of a static variable in c which is pretty much what OP wanted

Comment: This does not work if the function is called in succession with different files; it will always return based on the content of the first file opened.

Comment: Why `setattr` instead of simple dot notation?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the lines in a keyword argument declared with a mutable default value:

```
def is_in_file(element, path, lines=[]):
    if lines:
        return element in lines
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines += [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    return element in lines
```

***Caveat:***
you must be sure that this function is only called with one file; if you call it with a second file, it will not open it and continue to return values based on the first file opened.

#### A more flexible solution:

A more flexible solution is maybe to use a dictionary of lines, where each new file can be opened once and stored, using the path as key; you can then call the function with different files, and get the correct results while memoizing the contents.

```
def is_in_file(element, path, all_lines={}):
    try:
        return element in all_lines[path]
    except KeyError:
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            all_lines[path] = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
        return element in lines
```

#### OO solution:

Create a class to encapsulate the content of a file, like what @SergeBallesta proposed; although it does not address exactly what you requested, it is likely the better solution in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `functools.lru_cache` decorator to set up a helper function that reads in any given file only once and then stores the result.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def read_once(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        print('reading {} ...'.format(path))
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

def in_file(element, path):
    return element in read_once(path)
```

Demo:

```
>>> in_file('3', 'file.txt')
reading file.txt ...
True
>>> in_file('3', 'file.txt')
True
>>> in_file('3', 'anotherfile.txt')
reading anotherfile.txt ...
False
>>> in_file('3', 'anotherfile.txt')
False
```

This has the serious advantage that `in_file` does not have to be called with the same file name every time.

You can adjust the `maxsize` argument to a higher number if you want more than one file to be cached at any given time.

Lastly: consider at set for the return value of `read_once` if all you are interested in are membership tests.

Answer (score 1):

This answer proposes a class similar similar to Serge Ballesta's idea.

The difference is that it totally feels like a **function** because we use it's `__call__` method instead of dot-notation in order to conduct the search.

In addition, you can add as many searchable files as you want.

Setup:

```
class in_file:
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    def add_path(self, path):
        with open(path) as f:
            self.files[path] = {line.strip() for line in f}

    def __call__(self, element, path):
        if path not in self.files:
            self.add_path(path)
        return element in self.files[path]

in_file = in_file()
```

Usage

```
$ cat file1.txt 
1
2
3
$ cat file2.txt 
hello
$ python3 -i demo.py 
>>> in_file('1', 'file1.txt')
True
>>> in_file('hello', 'file1.txt')
False
>>> in_file('hello', 'file2.txt')
True
```